# Cannot run a Rust application in a Docker image: "not yet stable as a const fn"

Tags: docker, rust

I am following [the tutorial to run a Rust application in a Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/rust/). I have the following contents in my Dockerfile:

```
FROM rust:1.23.0

WORKDIR src/main

COPY . .

RUN cargo install

CMD ["main"]
```

When I run this using `docker build -t my-rust-app .`, I get the following error:

```
error: `std::sync::atomic::AtomicBool::new` is not yet stable as a const fn
   --> /usr/local/cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/yansi-0.4.0/src/paint.rs:274:30
    |
274 | static ENABLED: AtomicBool = AtomicBool::new(true);
    |                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |
    = help: in Nightly builds, add `#![feature(const_atomic_bool_new)]` to the crate attributes to enable

error: aborting due to previous error

error: Could not compile `yansi`.
```

What can I do to resolve this error and run the Rust application within a Docker container?  I have been looking at this for a few hours, and have tried variations of `rustup update` and `cargo update` within my Dockerfile, but none of these installation have resolved the error.

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. We cannot tell what crates, types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. Ideally, produce something that reproduces your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org). There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `AtomicBool::new` as a const was [stabilized in Rust 1.24.0](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/46287/commits/6c5f53e65ee5f022611033dbf58c42e26be7f93d). Using that version (or any newer) to compile with solves your problem:

```
FROM rust:1.24.0
```